# How to search on Twitter 1.1 without auth?

Tags: twitter

Twitter no longer allows default search widgets which use `search.twitter.com/search.json`
(It returns empty results for everything

Since 1.1 requires Auth, how can we put customized json queries on our sites just using javascript?

Twitter's new widgets return the result in html formatted form, so we can't use that either..

What should we do know? How do you do it now without auth?